# Actionbar like evernote - up button and tabs in one row on top with menu actions at bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have app which has actionbar containing 
1) up button which opens side bar menu for navigation just like google plus 
2) 2 action menu buttons 
3) 2 tabs implemented via view pager

I have successfully implementing actionbar using actionbarsherlock and the result is - > [image]

[image]

i want to implement something like evernote app where up button and tabs are in one row and action menu uses split actionbar . i have icons for tabs so fitting them with up button in one row is not an issue

can someone please point me in right direction as to how i can have  have up button in the same horizontal bar as tab by modifying actionbarsherlock lib .

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392541/replicate-actionbar-tabs-with-custom-view?rq=1 
code snippet by @DavidBriggs on this link solves the problem :)

Comment: problem still remains :( not working for Ice cream sandwich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

//enabling embedded tabs

```
//pre-ICS
if (actionBarSherlock instanceof ActionBarImpl) {
    enableEmbeddedTabs(actionBarSherlock);

//ICS and forward
} else if (actionBarSherlock instanceof ActionBarWrapper) {
    try {
        Field actionBarField = actionBarSherlock.getClass().getDeclaredField("mActionBar");
        actionBarField.setAccessible(true);
        enableEmbeddedTabs(actionBarField.get(actionBarSherlock));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error enabling embedded tabs", e);
    }
}

//helper method
private void enableEmbeddedTabs(Object actionBar) {
    try {
        Method setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod = actionBar.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setHasEmbeddedTabs", boolean.class);
        setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.setAccessible(true);
        setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.invoke(actionBar, true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error marking actionbar embedded", e);
    }
}
```

for further reference - 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/actionbarsherlock/hmmB1JqDeCk