# ViewPager with icon only

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, swipe, viewpagerindicator

I'm trying to implement an ViewPager with the page title containing only an image/icon (Drawable).

I tried using J.W. ViewPagerIndicator, but it doesn't support icons only. The best I got is that I managed to display the icon, but is not centered(it is displayed on the left - like there is some text in the page title, but is not visible).
I also tried to modify the library, but haven't managed to implement something that satisfies my needs for this (also I would prefer not to modify an library).

Can you guys recommend some other library or some good tutorial to implement custom ViewPager ?

PS: I'm trying to do something like the Twitter android application has.

Thank you.

LE:

After more searches and documentation I found that it can be achieved through reflection ... also I have found this method that works for now:

```
private void forceStackedTabs() {
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    if ( ab instanceof ActionBarImpl ) {
        // Pre-ICS
        disableEmbeddedTabs( ab );
    } else if ( ab instanceof ActionBarWrapper ) {
        // ICS
        try {
            Field abField = ab.getClass().getDeclaredField( "mActionBar" );
            abField.setAccessible( true );
            disableEmbeddedTabs( abField.get( ab ) );
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e( TAG, "Error disabling actionbar embedded", e );
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e( TAG, "Error disabling actionbar embedded", e );
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e( TAG, "Error disabling actionbar embedded", e );
        }
    }
}
private void disableEmbeddedTabs(Object ab) {
    try {
        Method setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod = ab.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setHasEmbeddedTabs", boolean.class);
        setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.setAccessible(true);
        setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.invoke(ab, false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e( TAG, "Error disabling actionbar embedded", e );
    }
}
```

This is the link where I found it: [forceStackedTabs()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15875381/2123401)

But I would prefer another method, because through reflection this code can break at any time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ActiconBar Sherlock library if you want twitter like application, [link](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-fragment-tabs-in-android/)

Comment: You mean I should use ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS, and add tabs?  And how should I implement icon's only for the tabs ? (the page indicator should still be there) ...
Also, the link you gave uses Text for the tabs, that's not what I'm looking for ... please see my question again...

Comment: Inside mainActivity that example making tabs , you can set only icon without text using  Tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.tab1);  dont use settext("tab1")

Comment: I see, and this will also have swipe capabilities like ViewPager has ? Or I should implement my gesture detector and change programmatically ?
I was thinking about combining TabHost widget and ViewPager LayoutManager ... can this be done with the ActionBar ?

Comment: I have tried the example from here http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html
and added tabs like you recommended with setIcon() and it is what I'm looking for :)

Comment: I have encountered a problem with using ActionBar for the tabs ... 
When changing from portrait to landscape the tabs move to the same line as the title and it seems I can't lock the ActionBar into Stacked mode.
What alternative do I have here in this case ?