# how to change the display amount of viewpager title?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-titlebar

Can i know how to change the specific amount of the view-pager title? Currently, the view-pager only able to show 3 title at once by default. In this case, i intend to change the total display amount into 5. I tried to use tab host and others layout cannot achieve what i want to display.

Actually what i want to display from the view-pager is the icon to be display, i want to display 5 icon on the title there, is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: and the attached image is what i really want,
http://s17.postimg.org/wx5n6rji7/image.png
when we are scrolling , is scrolling the title bar, so when the title bar is scrolling, what it is actually scrolling is the behind icon,
so when the scrolling is done, it will display particular content
and the title want to animate like pagertabstrip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to implement the result that you want using the current Android viewpager api but there are external libraries that can make it work.

Here is another [thread (viewpager with icons only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357020/viewpager-with-icon-only) that is related to your question. The libraries that you can possibly use are [ActionBar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and [J.W ViewPageIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator).

Answer (score 0):

what you are asking for depends upon the screen width of the device, since you cannot say which device the user will run the app on, you cannot adjust the number of icons/title in the action bar. However you may want to look at

`android:showAsAction` - How this item should display in the Action Bar, if present. [flag]