# ActionBar Tabs "locked" below ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android-tabs, android-navigation

Is there any way, how to set that the Navigation Tabs will be displayed below Action-bar every-time? On my phone is the view like I want it to be - tabs below Action-bar - but on tablet are the tabs inside the Action-bar.

Is there any way how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 3):

You can not force tabs to be below the action bar.  You can, however, roll-your-own with a ViewPager and PagerTabStrip.  See the post below:

[Force stacked tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459902/force-stacked-tabs)

Also, the Android Developers docs have some info:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#PagerTitleStrip