# How to add back button on action bar with more fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-button

know anyone how can I add one back button one my action bar?Here it's [my acplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0doK3.jpg) and I want to add it before INFO button. 
I've try to add that code for action bar but it don't works:

```
  actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
  actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Here it's my activity:

```
public class TrailActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;
Intent intent;
Trail trail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    intent = getIntent();
    setContentView(R.layout.trail_fracment_main);


    trail = intent.getParcelableExtra("trail");
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, tell the ViewPager to switch to the corresponding page.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            InfoFragments infoFragments = new InfoFragments();
            infoFragments.setTrail(trail);
            Fragment fragment = infoFragments;
            return fragment;
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return new MapFragments();

        } else {
            return new WondersFragments();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

EDITED:
In the left part it's how should be looks my action bar with back button and in the right part it's the actually my application right now. So.. How can I make it to looks like the aplication from left part?
[image]

If anyone know please show me how I can do it.

Thx :D

Comment: Please crop the image and put only relevant part of image here in question body.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I've add the photos with my application and what I need to do... So, if you know how can I make it.... please show me.

Answer (score 0):

Implement OnBackStackChangedListener and add this code to your Fragment Activity.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Listen for changes in the back stack
    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
    //Handle when activity is recreated like on orientation Change
    shouldDisplayHomeUp();
}

@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    shouldDisplayHomeUp();
}

public void shouldDisplayHomeUp(){
   //Enable Up button only  if there are entries in the back stack
   boolean canback = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>0;
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(canback);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    //This method is called when the up button is pressed. Just the pop back stack.
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    return true;
}
```

If you are looking for Back Arrow beside the ActionBar tabs.Using Sherlock you can do it.Try this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12703960/2365507

Comment: It don't work with it or no... I don't have the back button.

Comment: @vlad if you use  actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true); it will enable back button in action bar.

Comment: if you can see on my code... it is enable but I don't have button :(

Comment: @vlad I edited my answer,please check and let me know.

Comment: I've use you code and that line of code  boolean canback = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0; give me every time false, so... I will have each time  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); Did you know why?

Comment: if you know why please tell me

Comment: @cavaler12345  if there are entries in the back stack,then only it will be enable.if there are no entries it will be false.